# How to install non Python software in a container built from python image

Tags: python, docker

I have a Python application that I want to containerise with Docker. I'm using a `Dockerfile` such as:

```
FROM python:3.9
WORKDIR /app
COPY myapp ./myapp
COPY requires.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requires.txt
```

Now, my problem is that I have to install certain dependencies that are not just Python packages, for example [tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract).

How do I install this in the built image? Is the `python:3.9` image built on top an OS, such as Ubuntu, where I can add software? If so, how? Or does it make more sense to start with a proper OS image, let's say debian por instance, and from there install tesseract and Python (using `RUN apt-get ...`), and then using `python -m pip ...` to fulfill the Python of dependences?

Comment: Almost all language-runtime Docker Hub images are built on top of a standard Linux distribution.  Looking at the [Docker Hub `python` image page](https://hub.docker.com/_/python), `3.9` is an alias for `3.9-bullseye` which is the name of a [Debian stable release](https://www.debian.org/releases/bullseye/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The python:3.9 image is based on the `debian:bullseye` image, so you can use apt to install tesseract like this

```
FROM python:3.9
RUN apt update && apt install -y tesseract-ocr
WORKDIR /app
COPY myapp ./myapp
COPY requires.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requires.txt
```

As for starting from a base OS image or from a python image, I always try to get as much for free as I can and use the image that I have to modify the least.

Comment: I'm completely new to Docker (I literally started yesterday), and my concern (perhaps it's silly) is to create images as light as possible. That's why I started from Python, instead of from Ubuntu por instance. Is this a thing? Isn't gettin "as much as you can for free" against the performance of the container execution?

Comment: The Python image is based on a Debian image, so the people making the Python image also opted for building on other people's images. If you want to save image space, you could go for an Alpine based image with `python:3.9-alpine`. Then the command to install tesseract is different, but the principle is the same.

Comment: The main reason that I advise against building your own image is that building a good image is hard. To illustrate, this is the Dockerfile used to create the `python:3.9` image: https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/bc889262ddb8a156020cc0df70a6eed88c609c99/3.9/bullseye/Dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to load the required `.tar` files, that you need to install specific package, or just use precompilied binary.

as you can see in [documentation](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract#installing-tesseract), they have binaries for ubuntu, debian and windows - ([load here](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/Home.html#binaries), [for ubuntu docker image](https://launchpad.net/%7Ealex-p/+archive/ubuntu/tesseract-ocr-devel)).
You can call them straight from supported python library or command line.

Also you should ensure to provide required language data (add those files in dockerfile), if required.